# How to accept an arraylist into a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist, arguments

just a quick question.. how do you accept an arraylist into a method? Right now I have:

```
public void getHandValue(ArrayList< Card > hand) {...}
```

Just the word "ArrayList" is coming up as an error. The arraylist is in my main args. I'm very new to java so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you imported it at the beginning of your class file?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: Can't accept it for another 9 minutes apparently. I will though.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice is to use List < Card > in your signature, too.  Even if you're passing an ArrayList into the method.

You should try to keep your methods as generic as posssible.

Comment: Personally, it's a pet peeve of mine when people use "ArrayList<T>" in a signature when they really just want a "List<T>"